# Why Javascript works in this way?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

So I saw someone's tweet in Twitter, mentioning that following script was given during a job interview.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i+=1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i)
    }, 100)
}
```

The interviewee was asked to predict the outcome of this script, and he mentioned it was obvious for him in his tweet.

For me, as totally new (or not interested) in Javascript, it is hard to catch why the result is neither of:

1) 0, 1, 2 sequentially. (as traditional 'for-loop')

2). printing 3 only once. (If iteration is fully done before the function is called)

but printing 3 three times.

Is this because Javascript is not a sequential programming language, or characteristic of Javascript, or both?

Comment: It's to do with scopes. Maybe you could try it out?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Just saying "scopes" is not all that helpful. The key things to understand include variable hoisting, co-operative asynchronous execution, and the JavaScript event loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand this, you need to understand how JavaScript is event-based and how scopes work, which is why, I assume, it is used as an interview question.

Basically, JavaScript is based on an event queue. In the example code provided, `setTimeout` does not execute the code immediately, but lets the engine know that the code should be triggered in 100ms.

The `for` loop, however, gets executed immediately. This in itself would not be a problem if you used a block scoped variable definition, such as `let i = 0`. For example, the following code will print 0, 1, 2:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i+=1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i)
    }, 100)
}
```

However, in the code `var` is used, which is "hoisted" to the top of the function definition, or in this case, the top of the snippet/file. So in reality, the code would look as follows to the engine:

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i+=1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i)
    }, 100)
}
```

This has an interesting effect: Now the for loop runs three times, increasing `i` to value `3`. *Then* after the for loop finishes executing, the `setTimeout` callback function gets called, which has the same `i` value in its scope (because it was hoisted). That is why it prints 3 three times.

Answer (score 2):

It's because when you declare variable with keyword **var** you declare global (in this case) variable. And now consider **for** loop as task to execute. **setTimeout** adds another task to execute, but after **for** loop is finished. So order of execution is:

1. Iterate 3 time with for loop. And increment **i** variable 3 times.
2. Log **i** variable 3 times, because you called **setTimeout** 3 times.

If you want to read more about it here is great article: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

But when you declare **i** variable with **let** keyword, it's local variable. Its scope is one single iteration of for loop. So for every single iteration there is different variable (it is not overwritten by next iteration),

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable with `var` the scope of that variable is the function where it's defined (if it's defined in a function) or global (as in this case it's not defined in a function). Because of this js will remember the value of `i` until the code is active.

The loop will be executed 3 times and it will set the variable `i` to 3, and it will not be changed anymore.

The `setTimeout` method will call the callback passed as first param after 0.1 seconds, when the value of `i` is already set to 3, so it will show constantly 3 in the `console.log` as it's the value of `i` during the callback execution.